# Tabular Response in Microsoft Azure Bot Framework (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, bot-emulator

I have created a bot using *azure bot SDK* and want to show response in *tabular* format.
Currently, I am retrieving data from DB in a *DataFrame* object, then using *DataFrame.to_html()* to convert it to *str* object and then sending a response to Bot Framework Emulator using :

```
await turn_context.send_activity(response)
```

On UI the response is presented as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVnWh.png)

I want to show a proper tabular structure. What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You can use the adaptive card.

Comment: Perfect !! Also, you can go through the reference link that I have mentioned in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adaptive Card.

> Adaptive Cards are an open card exchange format enabling developers to
> exchange UI content in a common and consistent way.

Provides a way to display data in a tabular form. : [Tabular form in Adaptive Card](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Table.html)

This way you can bind dynamic values in Adaptive Card : [Templating in Adaptive Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/)